# Set of functions on $C[0,1]$ with bounded derivative is compact

Tags: analysis, compactness, arzela-ascoli

Just want to check if my proof works or not. 

Question: Given $K > 0$, determine if the set
\begin{equation*}
Y = \{f \in C^1[0,1], f(0) = 0, \Vert f'\Vert_\infty\leq K\} 
\end{equation*}
is compact in $(C[0,1],\Vert \cdot \Vert_\infty)$. 

My attempt: if $f' \leq K$ for all $ x \in (0,1)$, then $Y$ is equicontinuous (by using $\delta(\epsilon) = \epsilon/K$ for each $\epsilon > 0$). 
Also, since for every $f \in Y$, $\Vert f \Vert_\infty \leq \Vert K(\cdot) \Vert = K$, then $Y$ is also bounded. 
Any convergent sequence $(f_n)$ in $Y$ converges in $Y$ (I think), making $Y$ closed. 
Hence by Ascoli's theorem, $Y$ is compact.

Comment: Excuse me. I have forgotten the meaning and name of the notation $C[a,b]$. I believe it has something to do with a vector space of polynomials, but I have forgotten exactly what

Comment: @FShrike $C[a,b]$ generally denotes the set of real-valued continuous functions on $[a,b]$.

Comment: @csch2 much obliged

Comment: I would guess that $Y$ is not closed. Probably we can approximate the function $$f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x)=\begin{cases} 0,& x\in [0,1/2],\\ K(x-1/2),& x\in (1/2,1]\end{cases}$$ uniformly by a sequence in $Y$.

Comment: All we would need to find is a function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is $C^1$, $\Vert g'\Vert_\infty \leq K$ and such that $g(x)=0$ for $x<-1$ and $g(x)=Kx$ for $x>1$. Then you can consider the sequence $g_n(x)=n^{-1}g(nx)$. We still have $g_n\in C^1$ and $\Vert g_n'\Vert_\infty\leq K$. We can check that $g_n$ converges uniformly to $g$. Now consider the shifted sequence $$f_n:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f_n(x)=g_n(x-1/2).$$ Check that $f_n$ is in $Y$ and converges uniformly to $f$. But $f$ is not $C^1$.

Comment: I guess you can take $g(x)=K(2x^2-x^3)$ for $x\in [0,1]$, $g(x)=0$ for $x<0$ and $g(x)=Kx$ for $x>1$.

Comment: Yeah fair play. With that, $Y$ is not sequentially compact -> not compact.

Comment: Yes :) maybe you can write an answer with the details I skipped (maybe with $K=1$ to avoid annoying factors)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Rewriting @SeverinSchraven's comment as an answer)

Take the function $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, defined by 
\begin{equation*}
g(x) = \begin{cases} 0, \quad x < 0,\\
K(2x^2-x^3), \quad 0 \leq x \leq 1,\\
Kx, \quad x > 1.
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
Define the sequence $g_n(x) = \frac{1}{n} g(nx)$ and the shifted sequence
\begin{equation*}
f_n: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}, \ f_n(x) = g_n(x - 1/2).
\end{equation*}
Since $g \in C^1[0,1]$, then $f_n \in C^1[0,1]$ for all $n$. 
Also, for all $n$, $\Vert f_n' \Vert = \Vert g_n' \Vert = \Vert g'(n(\cdot)) \Vert = K$, since $|4x-3x^2| \leq 1$ for all $0 \leq x \leq 1$. Hence $(f_n)$ is a sequence in $Y$.
But $(f_n)$ converges to the function
\begin{equation*}
f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}, \ f(x) = \begin{cases} 
0, \quad x \leq 1/2,\\
K(x-1/2), \quad x > 1/2,
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
which is not in $C^1[0,1]$. Hence $Y$ is not sequentially compact, thus not compact.

Comment: In fact $Y$ is not even closed in $C([0,1])$ :)